# Using toggleClass for both buttons - Issue with $(this) jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to make flip colors of 2 buttons when mouse is over on one of them. I have the following HTML :

```
 <div id="PlayerVsComputer" class="checkbox">                                        
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="game">                                        
   <div class="btn-group" role="group"> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse btn-xs">Player</button>             
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-classic btn-xs">Computer</button>            
   </div>
  </label>
 </div>

 <div id="Player1VsPlayer2" class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="game">
   <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse btn-xs">Player 1</button>           
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">Player 2</button>                       
   </div>
  </label>
 </div>
```

and CSS :

```
.btn-classic {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  }


.btn-inverse {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;                                                               
  }
```

Firstly, I am focused on the first button group whose div container is `id="PlayerVsComputer"`. I tried to select both button with `.btn class` by doing :

```
var playerVsComputerContainer = $('#PlayerVsComputer .btn');
```

and create the following function when mouse is over on one of the 2 buttons :

```
playerVsComputerContainer.hover(function() {                                          
                   $(this).toggleClass('btn-inverse');                                   
                   $(this).toggleClass('btn-classic');                                   
   });
```

I realized that `playerVsComputerContainer` may be a array of jQuery Object (**idea to confirm**) because on Javascript console, I get :

```
>> $('#PlayerVsComputer button.btn'); 

Object { 0: button.btn.btn-inverse.btn-xs, 1: button.btn.btn-classic.btn-xs, length: 2, ...
```

From this, I tried to select only one button by doing :

```
playerVsComputerContainer.hover(function() {                                          
                   $(this)[0].toggleClass('btn-inverse');                                   
                   $(this)[0].toggleClass('btn-classic');                                   
   });
```

But it seems that `$(this)[0]` is not valid. So I did upstream :

```
playerVsComputerContainer[0].hover(function() {                                          
                   $(this).toggleClass('btn-inverse');                                   
                   $(this).toggleClass('btn-classic');                                   
   });
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I just want that colors of 2 side to side buttons flip their initial color (black and white) when mouse is over it (later, I want this change of current color to be confirmed by user with a mouse click).

You can see the test on this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/0vsddudc/3/)

```js
var playerVsComputerContainer = $('#PlayerVsComputer .btn');
playerVsComputerContainer.mouseover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('btn-inverse');
  $(this).toggleClass('btn-classic');
  //$(this)[0].toggleClass('btn-inverse');
  //$(this)[0].toggleClass('btn-classic');
});
```

```css
.btn-classic {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

.btn-inverse {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="PlayerVsComputer" class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="game">                                        
   <div class="btn-group" role="group"> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse btn-xs">Player</button>             
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-classic btn-xs">Computer</button>            
   </div>
  </label>
</div>

<div id="Player1VsPlayer2" class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="game">
   <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse btn-xs">Player 1</button>           
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-classic btn-xs">Player 2</button>                       
   </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

**UPDATE 1:** I have to precise that I want original colors to appear again when mouse is out of 2 side to side buttons : Must I use `hover` or `mouseover` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the same function can function as handlerIn and handlerOut, there is no need to pass the same function as the second parameter to the `.hover` method.
Refer [this](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) for jQuery `.hover` specification.

Check this code snippet.
May be this is the behavior you are looking for.
When the mouse is over a button, it toggles.
When the mouse moves out of the button, it toggles back to the original style.

In your html, the class name is misspelled as `btn-clssic`.
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-clssic btn-xs">Computer</button>`

The correction required in your code is

```
   playerVsComputerContainer.hover(function() {                                          
                   $(this).toggleClass('btn-inverse');                                   
                   $(this).toggleClass('btn-classic');                                   
   });
```

This can be simplified as following.

```
playerVsComputerContainer.hover(function() {                                          
                       $(this).toggleClass('btn-inverse btn-classic');                                   
       });
```

Refer [this](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) for jQuery toggleClass specification.

```js
$('#PlayerVsComputer .btn').hover(toggle);
   
   function toggle() {
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-inverse btn-classic');
   }
```

```css
.btn-classic {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

.btn-inverse {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="PlayerVsComputer" class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="game">                                        
   <div class="btn-group" role="group"> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse btn-xs">Player</button>             
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-classic btn-xs">Computer</button>            
   </div>
  </label>
</div>

<div id="Player1VsPlayer2" class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="game">
   <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse btn-xs">Player 1</button>           
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-classic btn-xs">Player 2</button>                       
   </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: -@raghu Thanks ! just a last question , in the expression `$('#PlayerVsComputer .btn').hover(toggle, toggle);`, why did you set 2 times `toggle` ? there is one for `toggle() function` but what is the second one ? a boolean ? but it is not initialized if this is a boolean, isn't it ?

Comment: In fact, there is no need for the second parameter. The first parameter is the function to handle the "move in". The second parameter is the function to handle the the "move out". In this case, both "move in" and "move out" handlers are the same.  When only one handler is passed to .hover, it uses the passed handler for both "move in" and "move out". Refer https://api.jquery.com/hover/ for detail. I have corrected my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I need to change the color of the button when hovering over it.
this code uses 2 functions. one is performed when you hover over any button with the class .btn, the other when you remove the focus from the button.

```js
$('.btn').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass('btn-classic');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass('btn-classic');
  }
);
```

```css
.btn-inverse {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;                                                               
  }
  .btn-classic {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="PlayerVsComputer" class="checkbox">                                        
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="game">                                        
   <div class="btn-group" role="group"> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse btn-xs">Player</button>             
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-clssic btn-xs">Computer</button>            
   </div>
  </label>
 </div>

 <div id="Player1VsPlayer2" class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="game">
   <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse btn-xs">Player 1</button>           
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs">Player 2</button>                       
   </div>
  </label>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the answer in a bit. and moreover running code snippet gives the error.