# Changing color of two buttons side to side when mouse is going from one to the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47609813/using-toggleclass-for-both-buttons-issue-with-this-jquery-object/47610706#47610706), I can make flip the colors of two buttons side to side when mouse is over them.

HTML code is:

```html
<div id="PlayerVsComputer" class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="game">                                        
    <div class="btn-group" role="group"> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse btn-xs">Player</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-classic btn-xs">Computer</button>           
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

and the JavaScript that makes the reversing:

```js
// Flip buttons color when mouse is over buttons
$('#PlayerVsComputer .btn').hover(toggle, toggle);

function toggle() {
  $.each($('#PlayerVsComputer .btn'), function(index, value) {
    $(value).toggleClass('btn-inverse btn-classic');
  });
}
```

Now I would like the color of one to change when I come from the another one, i.e while mouse is still on `btn-group`, i.e on a `button`.

In my above code, **the case where I move mouse from button to the another one is not handled**: I have to be on button and go out of the btn-group to restore original colors state.

A similar behavior would be the behavior of `CSS` "`:hover`" property but in my case, I make invert the colors of two buttons in the same time.

Here's the JS Fiddle that I have to modify to get what I want:

[Make invert colors](https://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/0vsddudc/7/)

### Update 1

Following the solution suggested by `Mosh Feu`, **it is almost working**: when I move the mouse from outside on one of the two buttons, the color is changing correctly. When I put the mouse out of one of the 2 buttons, the original state is also restored well (left button black and right button white).

**Excepted a detail**: when mouse is already on a button and I move to the other button near to it (I precise without be outside of btn-group, i.e while staying on the zone of the 2 buttons), then, in this case, the colors are not inverted.

I suspect this issue could come from a very little space between the two buttons: normally, with Bootsrap and `btn-group class`, there shouldn't be this space, the two buttons are bonded without space.

You can see the result when I don't use mouseleave:

[without mouseleave](https://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/qohv2sja/20/)

and when I use your suggestion, i.e:

```
var buttons = $('#PlayerVsComputer .btn').mouseenter(toggle).mouseout(restore);
```

[with mouseout](https://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/qohv2sja/19/)

For the moment, I don't know how to handle the two approaches to combine them. (I am going to make tests including Bootstrap CSS since this little space, between the 2 buttons, which appears with JS Fiddle).

### Update 2

From the solution of Mosh Feu below, I think the issue is circumvented since one does (when restore function is called):

```
$('#PlayerVsComputer').mouseleave(restore);
```

and not:

```
$('#PlayerVsComputer .btn').mouseenter(toggle).mouseout(restore);
```

In this way, until mouse is not on `<div id="PlayerVsComputer">`, the toggle functionality is used on button, and so `restore` is only called when mouse is outside of `<div id="PlayerVsComputer">` block.

But what about the little space between the two buttons? how is it handled by jQuery? Why there's no changes when mouse is over this space?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve.. Can you describe it by steps? For example: At start, button A should be black and B is white. When I hover on A it should be.. and B should be.. etc..

Comment: -@MoshFeu for example : **1)** mouse is not on group of buttons (left button is black and right one is white) **2)** mouse is over left button, immediately, the left button gets white and right one black **3)** I move mouse on the right button (without being outside of group of buttons "`btn-group`", i.e mouse is still being on buttons) and I would like immediately this right button to be white and the left black. Is it a little bit clearer ?

Comment: It seems that hover is little buggy, try with mouseenter, maybe? https://jsfiddle.net/0vsddudc/8/

Comment: -@sinisake I didn't know "`mouseenter`, this seems to do the trick, regards

Comment: @youpilat13 It the clearest :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, here is my approach. If not, please, correct me.

```js
// Flip buttons color when mouse is over buttons
var buttons = $('#PlayerVsComputer .btn').mouseenter(toggle)
$('#PlayerVsComputer').mouseleave(restore);

function toggle() {
  buttons.each(function(index, value) {
    $(value).toggleClass('btn-inverse btn-classic');
  });
}

function restore() {
  buttons.eq(0).removeClass('btn-classic').addClass('btn-inverse');
  buttons.eq(1).removeClass('btn-inverse').addClass('btn-classic');
}
```

```css
.btn-inverse {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.btn-classic {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="PlayerVsComputer" class="checkbox">
  <label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="game" />                                        
  <div class="btn-group" role="group"> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse btn-xs">Player</button>             
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-classic btn-xs">Computer</button>
  </div>
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: -@MoshFeu I don't know if I can directly do it with only css. With your css above, computer button doesn't get black when mouse is over it. Moreover, I would like to associate the events of color changing to the change of variable values in my JS code, so `mouseenter` seems to be good.

Comment: `computer button doesn't get black when mouse is over it.` It should be? I was followed after your steps. `Moreover, I would like to associate the events of color changing to the change of variable values in my JS code` How so? If you can save js code and do it with css is better. Let me see the full picture and I will try to help..

Comment: @youpilat13 Can't be done with the CSS only because there's no _previous sibling selector_ (yet).

Comment: @MoshFeu I repeat an example of behavior expected :  for example : 1) mouse is not on any buttons (original state is left button black and right one white) 2) mouse is over left button, immediately, the left button gets white and right one black 3) I move mouse on the right button (without being outside of group of buttons "btn-group", i.e mouse is still being on buttons) and I would like immediately this right button to be white and the left black.

Comment: The **behavior expected** is also, by starting from **step 2** : 2) mouse is over right button, immediately, the right button gets black and left one white 3) I move mouse on the left button (without being outside of group of buttons "btn-group", i.e mouse is still being on buttons) and I would like immediately this left button to be black and the right white. Finally, when mouse is no more on any buttons (i.e outside of **btn-group**), the original state is back (left button black and right white).

Comment: In the following jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/qohv2sja/14/ , I don't know what to put in **restore** function to get default colors for buttons ("original state")

Comment: So are there 2 options, the difference is which is the **first button** the user hovered on?!

Comment: yes, there are 2 possibilities, first go on left button which gets white (and the right which gets black), **OR** secondly, go on the right button which then gets blacks (and the left white) **AND Finally**, when mouse is not anymore on both button (out of them), I would like to go back to the original state (left black and rith white)

Comment: I forgot to say that once one of 2 possiblities is done, the colors of buttons also invert when I move from one button hovered to the other one.

Comment: I was updated my answer. I'm not sure what you mean by `one of 2 possiblities is done`. Can you describe the step just like you did in the previews comments?

Comment: -@MoshFeu you can see the last details in **UPDATE 1** into my original post above. regards

Comment: -@Mosh Feu Great it works !!! you saved my life ... more seriously, what's the difference between my last jsfiddle on https://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/qohv2sja/21/ : it seems that you have set **mouseleave** on **$('#PlayerVsComputer')** jQuery object, is it a way to avoid the issue with the little space that I have mentionned in my last above comment ? if you could explain more precisely ?

Comment: I have just corrected the misspelling of **btn-clssic** to **btn-classic** on this jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/qohv2sja/25/ , thanks a lot !

Comment: My pleasure :) In simple words, we want to not change the buttons state unless A. The user hover on the other button, then we toggle the `class`es B. The user moved out from the `#PlayerVsComputer`, then we reset the `class`es.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

HTML:

```
<div id="PlayerVsComputer" class="checkbox">                                        
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="game">                                        
   <div class="btn-group" role="group"> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-clssic btn-xs">Player</button>             
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-clssic btn-xs">Computer</button>            
   </div>
  </label>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-classic {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;                                                               
  }

.btn-inverse {
  color: white;                                                                          
  background-color: black;                                                               
  }
```

JS:

```
 $('#PlayerVsComputer .btn').on('mouseover', function() {
      $('#PlayerVsComputer .btn').removeClass('btn-inverse');
      $(this).addClass('btn-inverse');
 }); 

 $('#PlayerVsComputer .btn').on('mouseleave', function() {
      $('#PlayerVsComputer .btn').removeClass('btn-inverse');
 });
```